# when I try to install a eclipse plugin, It ask for a eclipse.tmatesoft.com a login?

Tags: eclipse

when I try to install an Eclipse plugin, It asks for an eclipse.tmatesoft.com a login? I try to install svn plugin for eclipse with the connectors. This Login required window always pop up? how can I reslove this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9YVS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as you are using the wrong update site. You should better install the SVN plugin via the marketplace `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace`.

Comment: Thanks. There was nothing wrong with the svn plugin. It turns out that I already had a some 3rd party plugin in side a plugin list that require permit ion from eclipse.tmatesoft.com. As long as it was there I was unable to install any other plugins.once I found out and remove that from the plugins list. problem solved.